# Getting a list/array of all organic groups a user is part of

Tags: 7, users, organic-groups, database

I have been searching online for awhile and so far I have been unable to find any og functions that will give me an array or list of all groups a user is a member of.  Does such a function exist?  If not, is there a sql query I could run that would give me this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you are using Drupal 7 and latest OG you can use [og_get_groups_by_user()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!og!og.module/function/og_get_groups_by_user/7).

> Get the group IDs of all the groups a user is an approved member of.

Comment: How can the same thing be done using Views Services Drupal 7 module?

Comment: Can this be done with a view? I'm not sure how to use that hook or function to make a view.

Answer (score 0):

Although I am a big fan of `og_get_groups_by_user()`, sometimes a bit more control about what is returned with the membership data is useful.

Here's a starter query that'll get you all the group nodes a particular user is a member of:

```
$uid = 123;

$query = db_select('og_membership', 'ogm');
$query->condition('ogm.type', OG_MEMBERSHIP_TYPE_DEFAULT);
$query->condition('ogm.etid', $uid);
$query->condition('ogm.entity_type', 'user');
$query->condition('ogm.group_type', 'node');

$query->join('node', 'n', 'n.nid = ogm.gid');
$query->fields('n', ['nid', 'title']);
$query->condition('n.type', 'group');
$query->orderBy('n.title', 'ASC');

$rows = $query->execute();
foreach ($rows as $row) {
  drupal_set_message(t('Member of @group', ['@group' => $row->title]));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The user groups can also obtained by loading the user.
For ex:
 `$test_user = user_load(2);
   $groups = $test_user['og_user_node']; // returns all group ids of a user`